# Why am I getting "unresolved reference" when trying to call isActiveSubscriptionId?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Android SDK [SubscriptionManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager) class is documented as containing three similar methods: [isActiveSubscriptionId](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager#isActiveSubscriptionId(int)), [isUsableSubscriptionId](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager#isUsableSubscriptionId(int)), and [isValidSubscriptionId](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager#isValidSubscriptionId(int)). The second two work fine, but I cannot get the first to even compile - no matter what I do (Gradle Wrapper from the command line, Android Studio), I get "unresolved reference". I even ran `strings` against `android.jar` from the SDK, and found `isActiveSubscriptionId` there - what am I missing? (I currently have both `compileSdk` and `targetSdkVersion` at 34.)

**Update:** When I manually add the appropriate import directive (which Android Studio refuses to do automatically):

```
import android.telephony.SubscriptionManager.isActiveSubscriptionId
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot import 'isActiveSubscriptionId', functions and properties can be imported only from packages and objects